# Fetch multiple columns from multiple tables where any table may have 0 or any number of rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table schema as below. Need to fetch details from many tables in MySQL.

[image: SCHEMA OF TABLES]

Here we need to fetch details from many tables, which have one to many relation in many places. Any table may return 0 or more rows.

I have done the fetching by `GROUP_CONCAT` and `SEPARATOR '|'` . below is my stored procedure -

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `P_GET_PROFILE`(
IN IN_USER_ID INT)
BEGIN
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_blacklist`.`ID` SEPARATOR '|') AS BLOCKED_ID,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_career`.`ID` SEPARATOR '|') AS CAREER_ID,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_career`.`CAREER_TYPE` SEPARATOR '|') AS CAREER_TYPE,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_career`.`ORGANIZATION_NAME` SEPARATOR '|') AS ORGANIZATION_NAME,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_career`.`FROM` SEPARATOR '|') AS FROM_DATE,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_career`.`TO` SEPARATOR '|') AS TO_DATE,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_career`.`CURRENTLY_DOING` SEPARATOR '|') AS CURRENTLY_DOING,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_friend`.`FRIEND_ID` SEPARATOR '|') AS FRIEND_ID,
`t_macroworld_login_management`.`LOGIN_TIMESTAMP` AS LOGIN_TIMESTAMP,
`t_macroworld_login_management`.`LOGOUT_TIMESTAMP` AS LOGOUT_TIMESTAMP,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`FIRST_NAME` AS FIRST_NAME,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`LAST_NAME` AS LAST_NAME,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`EMAIL_ID` AS EMAIL_ID,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`MOBILE_NUMBER` AS MOBILE_NUMBER,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`EXTENTION` AS EXTENTION,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`DATE_OF_BIRTH` AS DATE_OF_BIRTH,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`GENDER` AS GENDER,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`USER_TYPE` AS USER_TYPE,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`DP_URL` AS DP_URL,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`ADHAR_NUMBER` AS ADHAR_NUMBER,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`ADHAR_VERIFIED` AS ADHAR_VERIFIED,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`MOBILE_VERIFIED` AS MOBILE_VERIFIED,
`t_macroworld_registration`.`EMAIL_VERIFIED` AS EMAIL_VERIFIED,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_user_address`.`ID` SEPARATOR '|') AS ADDRESS_ID,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_user_address`.`LIVING_STATUS` SEPARATOR '|') AS LIVING_STATUS,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_user_address`.`LATITUDE` SEPARATOR '|') AS LATITUDE,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_user_address`.`LONGITUDE` SEPARATOR '|') AS LONGITUDE,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_user_interests`.`ID` SEPARATOR '|') AS INTEREST_ID,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_user_interests`.`INTEREST_CATEGORY` SEPARATOR '|') AS INTEREST_CATEGORY,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_user_interests`.`INTEREST_SUB_CATEGORY` SEPARATOR '|') AS INTEREST_SUB_CATEGORY,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `t_macroworld_user_interests`.`OTHER` SEPARATOR '|') AS OTHER
FROM `macroworld`.`t_macroworld_registration`
LEFT JOIN `t_macroworld_blacklist` ON`t_macroworld_blacklist`.`BLOCKED_USER`=`t_macroworld_registration`.`ID` 
LEFT JOIN `t_macroworld_career` ON `t_macroworld_career`.`USER_ID`=`t_macroworld_registration`.`ID` 
LEFT JOIN `t_macroworld_friend` ON `t_macroworld_friend`.`ID`= `t_macroworld_registration`.`ID` 
LEFT JOIN `t_macroworld_login_management` ON `t_macroworld_login_management`.`ID`=`t_macroworld_registration`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN `t_macroworld_user_address` ON `t_macroworld_user_address`.`USER_ID`=`t_macroworld_registration`.`ID`
LEFT JOIN `t_macroworld_user_interests` ON `t_macroworld_user_interests`.`USER_ID`=`t_macroworld_registration`.`ID`
where `t_macroworld_registration`.`ID`= IN_USER_ID;
END
```

Can any one suggest a better solution for this. Any hint from mysql prospective needed.

Comment: That's a whole lot of schema and not a whole lot of question. Can you inline your SQL code as well? External links can expire, plus they're very annoying for people to have to reference in another window or tab.

Comment: Use table aliases to make it more readable. The number of columns cannot be reduced if you need all of that information. If some of the information is constant and doesn't change often then can be abstracted into views to make the query looks smaller.

Comment: @tadman SQL is in github. Please read the question before commenting. Github is also a trusted source and never expires.It may be annoying for you but it is more annoing for me to copy in code section all Stored procedure.

Comment: @O.Jones I just need to fetch the data, what will be the requirement then? I stated that only

Comment: It's an external resource. You could delete that repository. You could edit that code. It doesn't matter if it's GitHub or not: It's not in your question where it belongs. *Please keep your question self-contained*.

Comment: added SP content, now it is self-contained.

Comment: For what purpose will you use "the data" once you fetch it?  If you're doing a backup or migration use `mysqldump`.  It will preseve your tables and relationships.  Using a single query to fetch "the data" from a database of this complexity just flattens it out and makes it more-or-less useless, except maybe to load into a text file and use text-editor searching.

Comment: I need to display the whole profile details and provide for update. to fetch I have tried in single stored procedure, which is there in the question.But it is becoming little bit complex.So splitted the SP and got the required things.